# Learning PHP and web-programming for intermediate programmers

Tags: php

I would like to know some good resources (book or website) on learning PHP for those who are already familiar with programming.

Many of the tutorials I've been finding are for people who never programmed before and take way to long to go through to even learn basic language constructs.

The optimal resource would not assume previous web-development background however.

Comment: What do you consider 'familiar' with programming?  What languages do you have experience with?  Do you have database experience?  What platforms are you comfortable with?  Do you know anything about Unix administration?

Comment: I'm a fourth year university student, but I've been programming since I was about 10. I know VB, C/C++, C#, Java and Python all to varying degrees. I have basic UNIX knowledge, and I am familiar with database interaction (I know some basic SQL and how to interact with it in Java).

Comment: a great resource for modern php:
http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Closed as off topic? Always seems to happen with questions like these. Moderators need to be more open minded. This is genuinely helpful info, and it ranks number 1 on Google. It is spot on topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) is what I used, especially with the search box in Firefox. Type in a function name and go. If you haven't already, it's probably worth browsing through while you wait for more answers.

Answer (score 4):

Learning raw PHP is probably the wrong way to go if you're already an experienced programmer.  I'd recommend picking up one of the frameworks, such as PHP Cake, Code Ignitor or Symfony.  These frameworks attempt to enforce the set of best-practices that have developed for PHP developers over the past six or seven years.

To that end, Symfony has a great, ["24 hours" style tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/) that can get you up and running with their framework, which will sneakily expose you to writing PHP code.  Even if you decide you don't like symfony, concepts such as MVC, routing, templating, ORM, etc. will be covered.   The other frameworks have similar tutorials, but I like the 24, one hour lessons approach.

For questions on specific PHP core functions/classes, [php.net](http://php.net) serves as a good resource (although the document of some of the core helper classes like XMLReader and the Reflection hierarchy can be sparse).

Answer (score 3):

This site has some good stuff:

> http://tizag.com

Whenever I am teaching anybody stuff I tell them to just Google "php [insert what you want to do]" and it will usually be in the first few results.

Another option:

> http://php.net

Answer (score 2):

Use http://www.w3schools.com.  They've got a great tutorial for beginning and intermediate php programmers.  Also, the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/docs.php) is fantastic.

Comment: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

I definitely use the official site at php.net and O'Reilly's PHP Cookbook most often.

As well, the zend development zone, http://devzone.zend.com/public/view and
Manning's PHP in Action book are useful resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old now, but I had a great learning experience with [The PHP Anthology](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpant1/).  If you check it out, please remember that it was published about 5 years ago.

A quick 'net search reveals there's a [new one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0975841998) on the market as well, but I don't have experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Some free PHP5 e-books](http://freeprogrammingebooks.com/free-programming-ebook/php-5/).

- Practical PHP Programming
- PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice

sounds nice

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with @stalepretzel -- the w3schools and php.net sites are both incredibly rich resources for both getting you started and keeping you going.

For video tutorials (screencasts), you really can't beat "In the Woods - Diving into PHP" -- The first video is here: http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/diving-into-php-video-series/

Handy dandy quick ref here: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/

When/if you get stuck on a specific problem you can always come back here to SO.

- Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

What is your opinion about w3schools ? I recommend this website. This is suitable for beginners and advanced level too.

Also i would like to refer official PHP website and You Tube(Search Video related to PHP)